# Using Quickblox Xamarin.Android Binding

Tags: xamarin, quickblox

I have to use Quickblox in one of my projects in Xamarin.Android and iOS. Here are the urls of both bindings:

- https://github.com/ahaedike/quickblox-monodroid-bindings
- https://github.com/ahaedike/quickblox-monotouch-bindings

I want use methods like...

```
QBUser user = new QBUser(login, password);
```

Also there is no method like

```
QBAuth.createSession(login, password, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {....
```

How can I use Quickblox in Xamarin?

Comment: The project's Readme states that it is a WIP and only chat features were tested

Comment: yes, you are right, but I'm just asking for basic methods. Without them we can not do chat.